# Trying to get PRECISE vector coordinates using geom.asPolgon

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I've got a bit of a problem. A script I've written is trying to get the coordinates of every vector in a layer, which is MAINLY working:

```
output_file = open('c:/myfile.txt', 'w')
layer = iface.activeLayer()
for f in layer.getFeatures():
  geom = f.geometry()
  if geom.type() == 1:
    if geom.isMultipart():
      line = '%s, %s, %s\n' % (f['USRN'], f['Street_Nam'], geom.asMultiPolyline())
    else:
      line = '%s, %s, %s\n' % (f['USRN'], f['Street_Nam'], geom.asPolyline())
  elif geom.type() == 2:
    if geom.isMultipart():
      line = '%s, %s, %s\n' % (f['USRN'], f['Street_Nam'], geom.asMultiPolygon())
    else:
      line = '%s, %s, %s\n' % (f['USRN'], f['Street_Nam'], geom.asPolygon())
  unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
  output_file.write(unicode_line)
```

However, there seems to be an issue with the Y coordinates (in my case, I'm using WGS 84 (EPSG:4326). The longitude is coming out okay, but the latitude is not precise at all. For example:

```
-0.0920572,51.6096
```

Obviously, the longitude is fine, but the latitude isn't. This is an excerpt from a shape which is an oval, and the longitudes are all different. However, because of the lack of precision, the latitudes that are output for this feature are all the same (51.6096) which, when I put this into my software, renders it as a single line.

Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using QGIS 2.8.1.

Comment: Are you sure that your data is more precise than the coordinates you get? Did you try to open your layer with another software?

Comment: You can export the layer to csv, the geometry as wkt to compare coordinates to your script output.

Comment: As a CSV (and exporting the geometry as wkt), the geometry is a lot more precise and exactly as I'd need. Hmm... I was going to ask how I'd put that in my script, but I should just be able to copy/paste the geometry over and do a few replacements... (strokes beard)

Answer (score 1):

As klewis said, I can get the geometry (and with all the precision I could want) by exporting the layer to a CSV, and the geometry as wkt. This serves my needs perfectly.